# getting symbols(???) instead of Arabic letters in processed excel file

Tags: javascript, java, asp.net, .net, vb.net

```
Private Sub Convert()

Dim Workbook_Folder As String
Dim CWS As Worksheet
 
Workbook_Folder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingUTF-8-sig

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Workbook_Folder & "\" & "Othaim_EPOS.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig"

    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy '  Forks a copy of the sheet in a new, active WB
    'With ActiveWorkbook
        '.SaveAs Filename:=Workbook_Folder & "\" & "Othaim_EPOS.csv", FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False
        '.Close False
    'End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub



Converting the excel sheet to
```

I am getting error while using above code to convert excel sheet

getting symbols(???) instead of Arabic letters in processed excel file

Can anyone help me here

Comment: This would normally be due to using the wrong encoding.